# Using startActivityForResult from activity which was launched with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

My app consists of a service (which implements a state machine, responding to UI and network events) and several state activities, corresponding to the states of the state machine.

The state change uses `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` to launch state activities, so that the user cannot bypass the state machine and get "back" to the "wrong" activity.  This makes the "back" button exit the app.  (The state persists when the app is relaunched.)

I want to use `startActivityForResult` to launch a non-state activity.

When the non-state activity is launched, the parent state activity is stopped, as I would expect.

When the non-state activity calls `finish()`, the parent state activity is destroyed, rather than being (re)started, even before the parent's `onActivityResult` is called.

Is this because the parent activity was launched with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY?

Comment: BTW, this also occurs if the intent you start via `startActivityForResult` has the flag of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I found that this was the cause of the issue.

Comment: you can use on back pressed function to restrict user not to bypass the state machine and get "back" to the "wrong" activity

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem, and Adeel Turk solved it! thanks to you both!

**Occured when switch out/home pressed/call StartActivityForResult**, app will get "killed"(finished).

just add this to the second Activity.(MainActivity)

btw, my first one is startActivity(with pattern lock). second is MainActivity()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else{
        finish();
    }
}
```